# Java Generic array Jsonify

Tags: java, arrays, generics, gson

I have the following attribute in my object:

```
List<? extends IRespondentCompressed> attr;
```

I am using List<? extends IRespondentCompressed> because I need to be able to contain 3 types of objects that inherit from IRespndentCompressed.

When jsonifying this with GSON I get [{},{},{}].

This is the class that implements IRespondentCompressed

```
public class RespondentCompressed implements IRespondentCompressed {

    @SerializedName(value="id")
    private int Id;

    @SerializedName(value="inserted_local_time")
    private String InsertedLocalTime;

    @SerializedName(value="responses", alternate={"Answers"})
    List<IResponse> Answers = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return this.Id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(int Id) {

    }

    @Override
    public String getLocalInsertedTime() {
        return this.InsertedLocalTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocalInsertedTime(String localInsertedTime) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setResponses(List<IResponse> ans) {
        this.Answers = ans;
    }

    @Override
    public List<IResponse> getResponses() {
        return this.Answers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the part where you assign these `RespondentCompressed` objects into the list? And why use  `List<? extends IRespondentCompressed> attr;` when you can use `List<IRespondentCompressed> attr;`